# Do JobTracker and TaskTrackers fall under HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

I have been studying Hadoop for a while now but I am confused about JobTracker and TaskTracker systems.

I am not sure how to phrase my question but here it is:

**Do JobTracker and TaskTraker fall under HDFS or MapReduce category?**

or a more appropriate question could be:

**Can physical machines fall under HDFS or MapReduce category?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JobTracker and TaskTracker services are part of MapReduce, which you can read more about here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html

Physical machines can host both HDFS (NameNode, DataNode) and MapReduce (JobTracker, TaskTracker) services. In general, it's recommended to place DataNodes and TaskTrackers together on the same physical slave nodes for performance reasons. The TaskTrackers can read/write to the local DataNode.

Note that Hadoop 2 introduced YARN (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html), which replaces MapReduce.